# Typescript type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'false' error

Tags: typescript

I'm a little new to typescript and getting this error. Here is how I've defined a type:

```js
type QtyComponentProps = {
  loading: boolean;
  itemQuantity: number;
  itemPrice: number | string;
} & (
  | {
      isWarrantyItem: true;
      product: WarrantyProps;
    }
  | {
      isWarrantyItem: false;
      product: SearchOffers;
    }
);
```

I am getting error when I am rendering the component with `isWarranty`:

```js
<RenderQtyComponent
            product={product}
            loading={loading}
            itemPrice={itemPrice}
            itemQuantity={itemQuantity}
            isWarrantyItem={isWarrantyItem}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined types as `true` | `false`.

I believe you have made this:

```
const isWarrantyItem = false
```

It's `inferring` the type as `boolean` instead of `true` | `false`

A few possible solutions.

1. Directly pass `<RenderQtyComponent isWarrantyItem={false}/>`
2. Make the type explicit. Such as:

```
const isWarrantyItem: false = false

return <RenderQtyComponent isWarrantyItem={isWarrantyItem}/>
```

3. Type casting - `<RenderQtyComponent isWarrantyItem={isWarrantyItem as false}/>`

Comment: The value is coming as props to the component. Don't have a way to hard code the type to false or true.

Comment: Bypass it by Type casting -  `<RenderQtyComponent isWarrantyItem={isWarrantyItem as false}/>`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using  conditional types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

Here is an example of how you would achieve this with the code you provided:

```
type QtyComponentProps<TWarrantyItem = boolean> = TWarrantyItem extends true
  ? {
      loading: boolean;
      itemQuantity: number;
      itemPrice: number | string;
      isWarrantyItem: TWarrantyItem;
      product: WarrantyProps;
    }
  : {
      loading: boolean;
      itemQuantity: number;
      itemPrice: number | string;
      isWarrantyItem: TWarrantyItem;
      product: SearchOffers;
    };
```